# File manager doesn't remember the previous view

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-files

This behavior is bit annoying in pantheon files manager. I'm not sure this is really a bug or default behavior. When I go to the next hierarchy by clicking an icon, pressing "back" button takes me to the previous window. So far fine. But clicking "right arrow" takes me to the first folder but it should take me to the next folder(next to the previous selection).

If I'm confusing, there are A, B, C, D icons and I'm clicking C. Now I'm in new window with files C1, C2.... Now I'm pressing back button. And I'm selecting right arrow in my first window,now it should take me to the icon D, instead A is selected.

Files version: 0.2.4

Could someone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most recent version of Files (0.3) has fixed this behaviour with respect to the back button and the back key.  Returning to the previous folder using some other method does not remember current folder.

see https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1495896

Comment: Will try the version and keep you posted. Thanks! I thought from your comments  there it's fixed from version 0.2.3 - so had to open this question.

Comment: It's all fine in .3